# Execute cross database query in postgres

Tags: database, postgresql

I am using PostgreSQL

> PostgreSQL 9.0.12, compiled by Visual C++ build 1500, 32-bit

I have two identical database on same server. I need to fetch data from a particular table from fist database and insert those data into other table in second database. I have read something about "EXTENSION" in postgres but I still don't get idea about how to use it.

So which is the better way to do it?

Any suggestion would help so much. Thank you.

Comment: Your only option is `dblink` in your current version, but in a newer PostgreSQL you could instead use `postgres_fdw`, the SQL/MED foreign data wrapper support.

Answer (score -1):

first open

```
share/contribs/dblink.sql
```

it is the path where postgreSQL is installed.

when you open this file , you will find some operations. copy it and paste it to the query window of your database and execute.

In my case i have executed this operations on both database.

now you will be able to run following kind of code

```
select * from dblink('dbname=databasename port=5432; password=P@ssw0rd123','select "id" from "State"') 
as P("id" bigint);
```

Comment: Suggesting `dblink` is entirely sensible, but **don't** just copy and paste the SQL. On PostgreSQL versions that support extensions use `CREATE EXTENSION dblink;`. For ancient PostgreSQL versions instead use `psql -1 -f /path/to/dblink.sql` to load the extension.

Comment: P.S. not my downvote, hope the downvoter comments to indicate what *their* concerns are.